# Rounding problem in Java. Why am i not getting the expected results in this case?

Tags: java, rounding

I have a plugin that i made for Minecraft. It is used for massive ender dragon fights to divide the EXP fairly among everybody, based on the damage dealt.

It works but there's a hiccup that makes the equation miss experience.

Here's the code:

```
private void divideExpAmongstPlayersBasedOnDamageDealt(int exp, Map<Player, Double> damageMap) {
    double totalDamageDealt = 0.0d;

    for (Double value : damageMap.values()) {
        totalDamageDealt += value;
    }

    while (exp > 0 && !damageMap.isEmpty()) {
        Player maxHitterInList = Collections.max(damageMap.entrySet(),
                Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();

        double damageShare = damageMap.get(maxHitterInList) / totalDamageDealt;
        int expShare = (int) Math.round(exp * damageShare);

        if (expShare == 0)
            break;

        if (maxHitterInList.isOnline()) {
            sendPlayerMessage(maxHitterInList, damageShare, expShare);
            maxHitterInList.giveExp(expShare);
        }

        exp -= expShare;

        damageMap.remove(maxHitterInList);
    }
}
```

It finds the max hitter, awards them their share of EXP and removes them from the list, until there is no more EXP left to give.

The problem is that it misses points, forcing me to add `&& !damageMap.isEmpty()` to the while condition to avoid exceptions.. It prints the percentages accurately always (the sum adds up to 100).

Im thinking it has to do with the Math.round function, although i am in the dark as how to debug this. When i do the calculations by hand they work out.

Example (this literally happened): A mob grants `10` exp. Player1 did `57%` of damage, Player2 did `43%`. The percentage values get printed correctly, yet Player1 receives `6` EXP and Player2 receives `2`?? Last time i checked `0.57 * 10` equals `5.7 = 6` and `0.43 * 10` equals `4.3 = 4`.

What am i missing? Does it have to do with the round function or the way doubles work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a rounding issue but you are using the wrong value in your calculation.

You wrote *"Last time i checked 0.57 * 10 equals 5.7 = 6 and 0.43 * 10 equals 4.3 = 4"* but the formula you use is

```
int expShare = (int) Math.round(exp * damageShare);
```

and you update `exp` for each iteration of the loop

```
exp -= expShare;
```

which means for your second player `exp` is for 4 and not 10 as you assumed in your example so the real calculation is *0.43 * 2* which rounded is 2

So you need to separate between the variable used in the condition for the `while` and the one used in the calculation.

Comment: A good tip is to declare method arguments final so they never get updated and whenever you need to update them you make a copy and use that.